# Angular $scope why can't be changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I decided to take a look on Angularjs. Right after first steps in tutorial I tried to rename `$scope` variable. But it breaks all the things.

```js
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope) { ... }); // this works

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function(foo) { ... }); // this does not works
```

Why? Isn't it just local variable which is passed to the callback? Why must it have *specific* name?

Comment: Also, if you [keep reading the tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification) it will be explained, along with how to change the variable name if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is injected variable. This means that Angular will actually deduce it's value from it's name. That's why only "$scope" will work.

This holds true for any of parameters to controllers, services etc. If you define your own service, for instance, you will also inject it:

```
// You will not get instance of your service directly. Instead, just
// put it right into function parameter list, and it will get injected
// by Angular for you.
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope, SomeService) {
});

// Declaration of your custom service.
phonecatApp.factory('SomeService', function() {
});
```

You will find more on DI (dependency injection) in Angular in [this article](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', function(foo) { ... }]);
```

This works and is a good practice (to use [''...] not to rename $scope to foo :-)) if you later want to minify your js files.